# Publish SQL Server Express from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-express

I made my web app project and now i want to upload it to my HOST I published web app and now I want to publish my database like in Visual Studio 2010 publish to provider (data and schema) but in Visual Studio 2015 I can't find the option what should i do ? is there anything i could do ?

Comment: Well either you create the Database as code first, so your application will create it or you make a database export and let your Host import it.

Comment: You could import your database into a SQL Server Data Tools project, create post deployment scripts to seed the data, and right-click to publish.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with SQL SERVER.
it turns out the built in sql for Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have any option to export the Database or backup it.